# AJAX Calendar Extender - binding null to text as selected date

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, null

I have an AJAX Calendar Extender inside an ASP.NET Repeater, which binds date data from a table and allows users to change this. I have an issue however - if the date is null, it returns an error as it cannot bind null as a selected date. Are there any ways around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of worked around the issue for anyone else having problems - don't set the selected value in the ASP.NET code, set it when the row is bound in the code behind, so you bind only if it's not null.